# RP3 Pins not working?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, putty

I have a small problem: I want to use pin 13 [GPIO 27].
(pin 13 [GPIO 27] should output 3.3V)

I tried [in Shell (Putty)]:

```
gpio mode 13 out
gpio write 13 1
```

but nothing happened.

I also tried pin 40 and other pins, but it doesn't work.
But with pin 7 it works.

Is my pi broken? Or what is the problem.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Er?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: That pin 13 [GPIO 27] outputs 5V.

Comment: None of the Pi's GPIO output 5V.  Please edit your question and tell us what you are actually doing.

Comment: Ok thanks I changed it, but I only want to turn on the pin.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What does `gpio readall` show. PS this pin is `MISO`

Comment: Ok I solved it. (With the gpio readall command)
The problem was that the gpios swapped. e.g. pin 11 [gpio 17] was in fact pin 0.
The gpio readall befehl has shown the real values.

Comment: @Milliways please write a answer that I can give you the green check mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When experiencing problems attempting to change GPIO the FIRST step in troubleshooting is to check what the Pi thinks the state of the pins are.

There are a number of ways of doing this `gpio readall` will show all pins, and you can check the state before and after.

The Pi uses (at least) 3 different methods on pin numbering `gpio readall` will show all.

In this case you appear to be attempting to use Physical pin numbers when `gpio` is expecting Wiring Pi numbering.